# Javascript for server side userinput prompt

Tags: javascript

I have a basic javascript for my k6 tool.

It simply performs load tests againt the http url of my application.
Over here I am hard coding the url in my code. Any suggestions on how can I get a pop up asking me for url input and then if further execute the code.

I am running the code on my centos server.

```
import http from "k6/http"; 
import { check, sleep } from "k6"; 

export let options = { vus: 60, duration: "60s" }; 
export default function() { 
 let res = http.get("my http url"); 
 check(res, { "success": (r) => r.status == 200 }); 
};
```

Comment: Your guidance is highly appreciated !!

Comment: Always put your code and other related stuff in the question itself

Comment: ok. I am new to stackoverflow. So sorry for it.

Comment: use prompt function of javascript

Comment: I had tried using it. but it throws me an error. "Prompt returns error(). prompt is not defined". If possible can you mention where and what changes I need to make in my code. I am basically from admin background and new to development.

Comment: How are you executing that function?

Comment: I dont know how to execute the given function. If possible can you please help me edit the snippet that I have posted above with the required function. ? It would be of great help.